# How to use Dompdf for Magento2 step by step

Tags: magento2, pdf, 3rd-party-library

I want to convert my html file to pdf using Dompdf in my custom module, right now i already  update my module composer.json like this:

```
"require" : {
    "dompdf/dompdf": "0.8.1"
},
"autoload": {
    "files": [
        "registration.php"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "Vendor\\Module\\": "",
        "Dompdf\\" : "Dompdf/src/"
    },
    "classmap" : ["Dompdf/lib/"]
}
```

and when i tried to use Dompdf like this:

```
use Dompdf\Dompdf;

class Index extends \Magento\Customer\Controller\AbstractAccount{
 public function execute(){
   $dompdf = new Dompdf();
 }
}
```

i got an error saying:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Dompdf\Dompdf' not found

Comment: Please check in vendor dompdf/dompdf folder available, if not it means dompdf library not installed yet. try this command "composer require dompdf/dompdf" for install it. After completing that command you need to run setup upgrade command as well.

Comment: I am using Dompdf extension in Magento 2 but I facing an issue when generating multiple pdf in the loop, only one pdf generated and others not generated and show this error [2018-09-11 13:01:57] main.CRITICAL: No block-level parent found. Not good. {"exception":"[object] (Dompdf\\Exception(code: 0): No block-level parent found. Not good. at /var/www/html/corplife-at/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/src/Positioner/Inline.php:44)"} [] please help me how I fix this My code is: for($i=0; $i<$getQty; $i++) { /**********************/ $data = ' <html> <body> <h1>'.$coupon_code.'</h1> </body> </html>'; // $block-

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/136483)

Answer (score -1):

If you have such type of requirement kindly follow this link it will help you to do the same-

https://github.com/weprovide/magento2-module-dompdf

Hope this will be helpful